# Change event not calling macro Excel Vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of values in a column which I am targeting.
Once any of the values in that range changes, it is supposed to call a macro.
The macro I am calling works but my change event is not getting recognized. Is there something wrong with my code?

My change even macro is located on the sheet where the change event is happening:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$H$5:$H$32" Then
        Call SetAxes
    End If
End Sub
```

Do I need to be more specific with the range address?

Comment: `Worksheet_calculate` does not have `ByVal Target As Range`  and you cannot just add it expecting it to work.

Comment: @ScottCraner `Worksheet_Change` didn't do anything either

Comment: Worksheet change does not capture changes due to formulas.  You will need to save the values in another location then compare the values after calc, if different then save the new values in the other location and run the sub

Comment: So the question is, "Are these cells being changed by formula or by manual input directly in the cells?"

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks. I changed to back to `Worksheet_Calculate` and simply called the macro and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Target.Address = "$H$5:$H$32"` will only be True if that entire range changes at once.

To trap changes to one or more cells within that range, use [Application.Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-intersect-method-excel) like this:

```
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("$H$5:$H$32")) Is Nothing Then
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply used `worksheet_calculate` and called the function when anything changes on the worksheet.
All the macro it is calling does is set the axes, so I don't mind if it runs repeatedly.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

        Call SetAxes

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

as a workaround, you could add a function:

```
Function FakeChange() As Integer
SetAxes
FakeChange = 0
End Function
```

and add behind your formulas in "$H$5:$H$32" +Fakechange()
like: ='your formula'+ FakeChange()

This function will be triggered when the results of your formulas are changed